# How to display Live Data using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

### I would like to display time series data of stock prices and averages in a Python 3 project.

The data is currently **stored in a CSV file** which is **updated periodically** and my **interpreter is Anaconda.**

I've tried using

> Matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation()

However the **Figure window pops up without any axes** and **then fails to respond and crashe**s.

Here is my **Charting Class** in the Project:

```
class Chart:

    import matplotlib.pyplot
    import matplotlib.animation as animation
    plt = matplotlib.pyplot

    @classmethod
    def __init__(cls):
        fig = cls.plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
        global ax1
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        ani = cls.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, cls.animate, interval=1000, blit=True)
        cls.plt.show()

    @classmethod
    def animate(cls, i):
        xs = []
        ys = []
        ax1.clear()
        data = pd.read_csv('chart_values.csv')
        date = data['timestamp']
        last = data['last']
        short_ma = data['short_ma']
        long_ma = data['long_ma']

        xs.append(date)
        ys.append(last)
        ax1.clear()
        ax1.plot(xs, ys)
        ax1.set_title('Trade data')
```

*Note* *

*Another issue I encountered* was that I *needed to set an environment PATH variable* that pointed to /library/plugins in my anaconda dir which solves the problem of getting this error message:

> *this application failed to start because it could not find or load the qt platform plugin "windows" in "".*

**However it needs to be deleted as soon as id like to use any other program which requires PyQt**.

### * *EDIT* *

I've changed the code as per the responses but have yet to get the plot to load and display data continuously.

```
class Chart:

    import matplotlib.pyplot
    import matplotlib.animation as animation
    plt = matplotlib.pyplot

    def __init__(self):
        fig = self.plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
        self.ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        self.line, = self.ax1.plot([], [])
        ani = self.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, self.update, interval=1000, blit=True)
        self.plt.show()

    def update(self, i):
# I don't think its essential to pass the loc as a param just yet.
        data = pd.read_csv('chart_values.csv', header=0) 
        self.line.set_data(data['timestamp'], data['last'])
        self.ax1.set_title('Trade data')
```

I get the following errors after I KeyboardInterrupt the program :

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:
>   '2020-05-21T17:04:13.645Z'

As well as:

> RuntimeError: The animation function must return a sequence of Artist
>   objects.

Comment: It’s a little odd that you have ax and ax1. Where is ax defined?

Comment: Hi :) It was a typo that didn't have any effect on the outcome. The plot still doesn't show any axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I have a solution!

A few things to note:

- Matlotlib's Funcanimation lib doesn't work in Classes.
- Having the main project and Chart functionality in separate files allows you to run or instantiate them each on separate threads whenever you choose.
- Matplotlib has 2 ways of interfacing with their lib. Using the OOP API is recommended.
- A axis date formatter is needed to use the timestamp on the x axis.

#### The Updated Code

#### *chart.py:*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pandas as pd
import dateutil.parser
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np


def init():  # only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
    plt.ion()
    line = ax1.set_ydata([np.nan] * 1000)
    return line,


def update(i):
    ax1.clear()  # necessary to stop plots from being redrawn on canvas
    ax1.set_title('Trade data')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Date & Time')
    my_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')  
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(my_fmt) # Display Hour and Min on X axis 
    data = pd.read_csv('D:/Development applications/Trading Bot/Foxbot_v0.1/main/sources/ticker_history.csv',
                       header=0, index_col=0)
    line = []  # Different MA Lines to be placed onto the figure
    dates = data['timestamp'].iloc[-1000:]  # selecting last 1000 timestamp points to be displayed at any given time
    x = []  # empty list to store dates
    types = {  # dict: keys = features I wish to plot & values = color of the line

        'last': 'cyan',
        'short_ma': 'r',
        'long_ma': 'k',
        'base_ma': 'green', }

    for date in dates:
        x.append(dateutil.parser.parse(str(date)))

    for t in types.keys():  # iterate through dict keys
        y = data[t].iloc[-1000:]  # select last 1000 points where column = dict key
        line.append(ax1.plot(x, y, lw=1.5, ls='-', color=types[t], label=t))  # append the col pts to the line
        ax1.legend(types.keys(), loc='upper right')

    return line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3],  # return last and short, base, long moving avg


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=3000)
plt.show()
```

**That worked for me!**

Error:

I think the error might be related to the `i` variable in the `update()` method. I think the `self` or `cls` params get in the way of the interval being passed into `i`.